# In typeORM, 'transformer' is triggered even though the value of the model being targeted for the relationship is 'null'

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

when I use the property 'eager' for a relationship in typeORM, 'transformer' is triggered even though the value of the model being targeted for the relationship(name: Withdrawal) is 'null'.

What can I do to prevent this?
The attached pictures are my current code.
Thanks :)

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this happens because of the JOIN operation that takes place because of the eager relationship.

Let's take the most simple `find` operation below:

```js
findAll() {
  return this.lossAssessmentRepository.find();
}
```

Considering your entities, calling `await findAll()` will generate a query similar to the following:

```sql
SELECT 
  "LossAssessment"."id" AS "LossAssessment_id",
  "Withdrawal"."id" AS "Withdrawal_id",
  "Withdrawal"."userId" AS "Withdrawal_userId", 
  "Withdrawal"."lossAssessmentId" AS "Withdrawal_lossAssessmentId", 
  "Withdrawal"."bankCode" AS "Withdrawal_bankCode", 
  "Withdrawal"."accountNumber" AS "Withdrawal_accountNumber"
FROM "LossAssessment" 
LEFT JOIN "Withdrawal"
  ON "LossAssessment"."id" = "Withdrawal"."lossAssessmentId";
```

A sample of raw results would be:

| LossAssessment_id | Withdrawal_id | Withdrawal_userId | Withdrawal_lossAssessmentId | Withdrawal_bankCode | Withdrawal_accountNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lossAssessmentId1 | withdrawalId1 | userId1 | lossAssessmentId1 | bankCode1 | accountNumber1 |
| lossAssessmentId2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Now imagine typeorm converting this raw response to the entity class instances you have defined.

1. The first row will have no issue because it has non-null values for `Withdrawal` entity. So typeorm will first create `Withdrawal` entity and put it inside the `LossAssessment` entity.
2. The second raw needs to be converted to `Withdrawal` entity, and then that should be put inside `LossAssessment` entity. Here, I'm guessing typeorm does not care if all the values are `NULL`. It first tries to create the entity instance for `Withdrawal` which would call your transformer in the process.

---

You can simply modify your transformer to accept null values like this to fix your problem:

```js
transformer: {
  from(value: string | null): string | undefined {
    return value ?? decrypt(value) : undefined;
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I understand that it is an inevitable problem due to 'JOIN'.

Thank you for your answer!!